# I'm not sure what to do for getFlightTime() method, How to get time in millisecond?

Tags: java

Design the two classes Flight and Itinerary. The Flight class stores the
information about a flight with the following members:
• A private String data field named flightNo for the flight number.

• A private GregorianCalendar data field named departureTime.

• A private GregorianCalendar data field named arrivalTime.

• A constructor that creates a flight with the specified flight number, departure time, and arrival time.

• Appropriate getter and setter methods. (Hint: Do we need setter for flightNo?)

• A method named getFlightTime() that returns the flight time in minutes. Assume the departure-
Time and arrivalTime are in the same time zone. (Hint: Use the method getTimeInMillis() to get
arrivalTime and departureTime in milliseconds, compute their subtraction, and transfer the result
from milliseconds to minutes.)

```
    import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class TestFlightItinerary{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
    class Flight{
        private String flightNo;
        private GregorianCalendar departureTime;
        private GregorianCalendar arrivalTime;

        //Constructor
        Flight(String SpecNo,GregorianCalendar SpecDtime, GregorianCalendar SpecAtime ){
            this.flightNo = SpecNo;
            this.departureTime = SpecDtime;
            this.arrivalTime = SpecAtime;
        }
        //Getters
        public String GetFlightNo() {
            return flightNo;
        }
        public GregorianCalendar GetDtime() {
            return departureTime;
        }
        public GregorianCalendar GetAtime() {
            return arrivalTime;
        }

        //setters

        /*public void SetFlightNo(String Number) {
            flightNo = Number;
        }*/
        public void SetDtime(GregorianCalendar Dtime) {
            departureTime = Dtime;
        }
        public void SetAtime(GregorianCalendar Atime) {
            departureTime = Atime;
        }
        // getFlightTime method
        public GregorianCalendar getTimeinMillis() {

        }

        public GregorianCalendar getFlightTime() {

        }


    }
```

Comment: Your teacher has given you the answer... `departureTime.getTimeInMillis()`. Do that for both times, subtract, and divide to get minutes.

Comment: FYI, Java 8 introduced `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`, which provide cleaner APIs for dates/times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flight time (duration) is the elapsed time between the depature and arrival time (i.e duration = arrival time - departure time; both being in same time unit).

Since your method is named `getTimeinMillis`, I then guess you're expecting the flight time (duration) in milliseconds (represented as a `long`). Therefore, you should get both times (departure and arrival) in milliseconds for computing the duration (as described above). Should long not be expected, you may always use a different return type.

```
public long getTimeinMillis() {
    return arrivalTime.getTimeInMillis() - departureTime.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Since you already have the flight time in milliseconds, getting that in minutes in only a matter of convertion. You may use the standard [Java TimeUnit toMinutes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toMinutes(long)) or manually calculate it as follow:

***1 minute = 60 secondes = 60 * 1000 milliseconds***

Therefore, ***The number of minutes out of X milliseconds = X / (60 * 1000)***

```
public long getFlightTime() {
    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(getTimeinMillis());
    //or return getTimeinMillis() / (60 * 1000);
}
```

The above is returning the number of minutes as a `long`, which in most case is an overkill since `int` is normally enough for flight duration (in minutes). But of course, with the manual calculation you may use any type of return value depending on the expected precision.